# Rails 3: Writing a Joins Statement for a HABTM Relationship

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship between :users and :books. They're joined by the :owned_books model. One feature of my app is to connect users that have read the same books. At the moment, I inefficiently process this in my model:

```
  users_hash = Hash.new
  users = User.all
  users.each do |user|
    if user != current_user
      users_hash[user.id] = 0
      user.books.each do |book|
        if current_user.books.include?(book)
          users_hash[user.id]+=1
        end
      end
    end
  end
  users_hash = users_hash.sort {|a,b| b[1]<=>a[1]}
  @users = Array.new
  users_hash[0..max].each do |id|
    user = User.find(id[0])
    @users << user
  end
end
```

I believe there's a way I can get the database to do this work. I've been toying with a MySQL query that looks like this:

```
@users = User.select("users.*, COUNT(books) AS shared_books").joins("LEFT JOIN books ON ???").order("shared_books DESC").limit(100)
```

My intention is to join the books that the current_user has read, and then get a count for all other users to see how many of those books they have read. I'll then order the results by this count and limit to the top 100 results.

Unfortunately, my MySQL skills aren't up to snuff. In particular, I'm unsure how to write conditions for joined models. I also doubt that the select statement will work, though I can probably figure that out once I have a solid joins statement.

Comment: As a note, typically `{ }` is used in place of `Hash.new` and `[ ]` is preferred to `Array.new`. Calling the constructor is only required for customizing how the Hash or Array operates.

Answer (score 0):

If you structure your data correctly you can usually fetch what you want in a single operation. In your case, you might need to adjust it slightly to this structure:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :owned_books
  has_many :books,
    :through => :owned_books
end

class OwnedBook
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :book
end

class Book
  has_many :owned_books,
    :as => :owned_by
  has_many :users,
    :through => :owned_by
end
```

Using the newer `has_many :through` has a number of advantages over the `has_and_belongs_to_many` method, mostly because the implementation is more up to date but also because the way that association is used makes a distinction between data present in your join model and the model being joined. It's also a lot easier to manage the associations because each OwnedBook is actually a first-class model that can be altered, updated, or destroyed using an `id`.

To fetch users with common books in this case, try this:

```
User.where('id IN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM owned_books WHERE book_id IN (SELECT book_id FROM owned_books WHERE user_id=?))', @user.id)).all
```

This is a little long-winded because it will avoid duplicating users. If you simply fetched users with common books, you would potentially get multiple matches per user. This is why the `DISTINCT` condition is added to the query.

Comment: This seems to work, though without ordering the users. My intention is to order the users by how many books they share with the current_user. I tried reworking your code to do this like so: User.select('users.*, COUNT(owned_books WHERE book_id IN (SELECT book_id FROM owned_books WHERE user_id=?) AS shared_books)', current_user.id).order("shared_books DESC").limit(100)

Comment: Unfortunately, it's throwing an error: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

Comment: The `select` method takes a single argument, so that might not work unless you execute `sanitize_sql` on the query. If you make a class method that accepts a `user_id` argument and returns the results, you will have easy access to that method.

Comment: I've been tinkering with this for hours, but I keep getting syntax errors even after fixing the wrong number of arguments problem. My suspicion is that I can't use COUNT like this. In the examples I've seen, COUNT is used for preexisting columns. I tried switching things around and placing the COUNT directly inside .order, but then it no longer recognizes shared_books. Any advice on how to approach this problem?

Comment: This is the code that doesn't recognize shared_books anymore. It feels like the right direction, though: User.select('users.*').joins('LEFT JOIN owned_books AS shared_books ON book_id IN (SELECT book_id FROM owned_books WHERE user_id=?)', current_user.id).order("COUNT(shared_books) DESC").limit(100)

Comment: Yes, `COUNT` must be performed on a singular column or `*` if you don't care what column. You probably want `COUNT(shared_books.id)` in the last case but may require grouping on `shared_books.book_id` to get the proper counts, such as appending `group('shared_books.book_id')` to your query chain.

Comment: This method gets me past the explicit errors, but the behavior is still buggy. In my sample, I have three users. The current_user has four books, two of which he shares with one of the other users. When I make this query without grouping or sorting, I get 18 results--6 of the current_user and 12 of the other user. I believe this is because there are 6 instances of owned_books, the 4 the current_user owns as well as the 2 he shares with the other user. When I add grouping by book_id, the results are slimmed down to 4, all of which are the current_user. I think there's a problem in my approach.

Comment: It might be best to start with a query that works and then try and rework it into something that ActiveRecord can better represent. The reason I was doing a straight-up `User.where(...)` call was to keep it as simple as possible.